# How to program delay?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, delay

I have two view controllers.

I made imageview (in the Gif file) in first VC. After 5seconds, I want page pass to second vc. First VC code is like this:

```
class LemonVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var LemonGif: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        LemonGif.loadGif(name: "sufoo")

    //        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 
    .seconds(4), execute: {
    //
    //        })
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

[image]

First VC name is LemonVC

Second VC name is SecondVC

Comment: I'd probably not start it in `viewDidLoad`, but might consider `viewDidAppear` for starters

Comment: I think the other command you're looking for is `performSegue` ... assuming you actually named the segue's between you view controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use a segue between the first and second controller to define a navigation path (drag from the "yellow" dot in the first controller onto the second controller.  This example uses a `show` kind)

[image: Segue]

Make sure you give it an identifier name, you need this in your code.

I would probably use `viewDidAppear` over `viewDidLoad`, at least it means that the view has transitioned to the screen.

Then, all you need to do is use `UIViewController#performSegue` to execute the segue, which will present the next controller

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5), execute: {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "skipTo", sender: self)
    })
}
```

Comment: Glad it could help - just remember, there's always more then one way to skin a cat - this is just one way to do what you want ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5), execute: {
// go some where
// example
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let introRootVC = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController() // it's main controller, if you want to another create Story board ID 
        self.present(introRootVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

You can change delay, **seconds(5)** <- here